# Saving several different variables

Tags: c++, save

For an experiment with different parameters, I want to save several variables from my C++ program:

a `vector<vector<Eigen::VectorXd>`

a variable for the running time

a `vector<int>`

How would you save this data / What can you recommend me to use?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using JSON. It's really useful in any situation.

More info about JSON: https://www.json.org/json-en.html